# How to make a Partially Filled Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to make a Partial array with this code in the Console Application. What I am trying to do is enter multiple values (Example test scores) on one Console.ReadLine, take the sums of the numbers entered, but if user inputs less than the LIMIT, for example inputs 5 values, but there is space for a total of 10, that it will just add up those 5 values.

I want to be able to enter multiple values using an Array on a single line, but if I dont enter values for each parameter in `int [] scores = {0, 1, 2, ...];` it should be able to add up the numbers entered by the user, and forget the rest. For example if I enter 56 76 86 on one line, then enter 0 terminating the array, it will add up 56 76 86, and not require other numbers to fill the array.

```
    class Program
    {
        const int LIMIT = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declarations:
            //Array Size
            //Array Scope




            int[] examScores = new int[LIMIT];

            //Define an Array of integers:
            int testNum = 1;
            int [] scores = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

            //1. Ask User Method:
                //a.)Ask user to input numbers.
                //b.)Save user numbers in an array

            Console.WriteLine("Input all of your test scores as the program prompts of");
            Console.WriteLine("each score on the lines below. (i.e. 89 25 87 98...)");


           //Purpose of this for method is to get user input and save to
           //an array.

            for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter test score #{0}", testNum);
                scores[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            PrintScores(scores);




            Console.Read();
        }//End Main.

        //2. AddSum Method. 
        //Purpose: Take users input and add all numbers together.
        //Paramiters: Array numbers from Main saved as PrintScores
        //Returns: None
        //Prints: Sum of Scores.
        static void PrintScores(int[] scr)
        {
            int result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < scr.Length; i++)
            {
                result += scr[i];
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of your test scores equal: {0}", result);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What _specifically_ are you having difficulty figuring out? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to be able to enter multiple values using an Array, but if I dont enter values for each parameter in {int [] scores = {0, 1, 2, ...];} it should be able to add up the numbers entered by the user, and forget the rest. For example if I enter 56 76 86 on one line, then enter 0 terminating the array, it will add up 56 76 86, and not require other numbers to fill the array.

Comment: @GoodyGoodmansen Then you should use a `List<int>` instead of an array.  Arrays must have a fixed size; lists do not.

Comment: @D Stanley I want to Split this so that all the values are entered on one line, then added together, but be able to be entered in Partially.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`string.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which splits a string into multiple parts based on a delimiter.

In this case, simply read all of the text in a single `Console.ReadLine()`, and split the strings into an array, parse them, and insert them into the `examScores` array.

```
string line = Console.ReadLine(); //Read the line of scores (Ex: 89 25 87 98)
int[] scores = line.Split(' '); //Split it between the spaces, into an array

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) //For each element in this array, set the score array to the same
    examScores[i] = scores[i];
```

It will only copy the number of scores inputted, the rest will remain the same.

Comment: I get a error from the int[] scores = line.Split(); stating that it cant implicitly convert string to int.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I understand what part you are having trouble with. But I think that the following changes to your code should accomplish what you want:

```
List<int> scores = new List<int>();

Console.WriteLine("Input all of your test scores as the program prompts of");
Console.WriteLine("each score on the lines below. (i.e. 89 25 87 98...)");

string line;

Console.WriteLine("\nEnter test score #1");
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "")
{
    scores.Add(int.Parse(line));
    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter test score #{0}", scores.Count + 1);
}
PrintScores(scores.ToArray());
```

The above will allow the user to enter one score per line (per your original code example), and when they simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering anything (i.e. they enter a blank line) it will stop trying to read more scores and will call your `PrintScores()` method to add them up.

**EDIT:** based on your clarification that the original code example is not representative of the behavior you want, here is an alternative implementation:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input all of your test scores as the program prompts of");
Console.WriteLine("each score on the lines below. (i.e. 89 25 87 98...)");

Console.WriteLine("\nEnter test scores: ");
int[] scores = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(text => int.Parse(text)).ToArray();
PrintScores(scores);
```

This will read a *single* line from the user, where a single space is between each integer entered. It converts the individual integers from their text format to an actual `int`, and finally copies that result into an actual `int[]` so that it can be passed to your `PrintScores()` method.

If you want to allow the user to enter an arbitrary number of spaces between each number, see the documentation for the `String.Split()` method for the option to pass to remove empty elements from the split result.

Comment: I want to Split this so that all the values are entered on one line, then added together, but be able to be entered in Partially.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("\nEnter test score #" +(i+1) +": ");
    scores[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (scores[i] == 0 )
    {
        while (i < scores.Length)
        {
            scores[i]=0;
            i++;
        }

    }

}
PrintScores(scores);
```

This way, when you enter a 0, it will fill the rest of the array with 0's, and now you can add only the values that you entered.